# Can I load a floating point # from a GP register

Tags: assembly, floating-point, mips

Can I load a floating point from a general purpose register like this:

```
lwc1  $f12, 0($t4)
```

It give me this error:
`"$f12": operand is of incorrect type`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually processors don's support something like this. Floating point values can be stored/loaded only to/from memory.
If you want to perform an operation equivalent to C's `union`, then store the value from your GP register to memory and then read it back in a FP register. If you want to perform a conversion from int to float, then use appropriate `load` instruction.